# How to set up multistore in sub domains in prestashop 1.7

Tags: subdomain, prestashop-1.7, multistore

We have domain.com as the main domain with some different apps in it.

We have prestashop.domain.com as a subdomain which is also a subfolder of root folder in the server public_html folder and contains prestashop installation core.

We want to have multiple shops with the help of prestashop multistore in this way:

- someshop.domain.com
- anothershop.domain.com

**Is it even possible?**

Because in the documents it says it is possible and it is done automatically by prestashop.
Check this : [https://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Setting+a+shop's+URL#space-menu-link-content](https://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Setting+a+shop%27s+URL#space-menu-link-content)

But it is not working for me anyway. I have been trying a lot of cpanel stuff.

It only works in this way:

- prestashop.domain.com/someshop
- prestashop.domain.com/anothershop

Answer (score 0):

in such configuration Prestashop is responsible to route requests to both subdomains with a unique **.htaccess** placed in root directory and , of course, a unique installation.

So you have to ensure to configure both subdomains document root in cPanel towards the same server physical path where Prestashop resides.

Then, make sure to set the physical URI to "/" for both shops in the multistore configuration, this should do the trick.